# Artin exercise 2.1.5.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Could someone look over my solution to this exercise in Artin's algebra text?

> Assume that the equation $xyz = 1$ holds in a group $G$. Does it follow that $yzx = 1$? That $yxz = 1$?

**Solution.** It follows that $yzx = 1$. We have: 
\begin{align*}
xyz = 1 &\iff yz = x^{-1}*1 = x^{-1} \\
&\iff yzx = x^{-1}x = 1.
\end{align*}
It does not follow that $yxz = 1$. For a contradiction, suppose it does. Then, we have: 
\begin{align*}
yxz = 1 \iff y^{-1} (yxz) z^{-1} = y^{-1} * 1 * z^{-1} \iff x = y^{-1}z^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Plugging into $xyz = 1$: 
\begin{align*}
xyz = 1 & \iff y^{-1} z^{-1} yz = 1\\
& \iff y(y^{-1}z^{-1}yz)\\
& \iff y\\
& \iff z(z^{-1}yz)\\
&\iff zy = yz = zy. 
\end{align*}
So $zy = yz$ for all $z, y \in G$. This contradicts the fact that not all groups are abelian. Hence, $yxz = 1$ holds if and only if $G$ is abelian, but not generally.

Comment: Yes this OK. You could do it a bit shorter using the first *and* second equation: you know that for all $x,y,z \in G \text{ } xyz=1$ and hence $yzx=1$, so if in addition $yxz=1$, you get $yzx=yxz$ for all $x,y,z \in G$. Cancelling the $y$ at both sides gives $xz=zx$ for all $x,z \in G$, meaning $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is OK but the second part is wrong.

The question is actually ambiguous. It isn't clear whether the condition $xyz=1$ holds for all $x,y,z$ or just for some $x,y,z$.

In your answer to the second part, you wrote (emphasis mine):

> So $zy = yz$ for **all** $z, y \in G$.

You seem to have implicitly taken the premise to mean $xyz=1$ for all $x,y,z\in G$. But in this case we should have $x11=1$ for all $x\in G$, i.e. $G=\{1\}$. Hence $yxz\equiv1$ and your answer is wrong.

If you take the premise to mean that $xyz=1$ for some $x,y,z\in G$, then your answer is incomplete. You have correctly shown that the condition $xyz=1=yxz$ implies that $yz=zy$. However, this does not lead to a contradiction because in *every* non-abelian group, there *do* exist $x,y,z$ that satisfy all these conditions (such as when $x=y=z=1$). So, in order to give a negative answer to the question, you should at least explain why there is some non-abelian group $G$ that contains some $x,y,z$ such that $xyz=1$ but $yz\ne zy$.

This can be done by picking a pair of non-commuting elements $y,z\in G$ and let $x=(yz)^{-1}$, or by exhibiting a concrete counterexample, such as $x=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr),\,y=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}2&3\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $z=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&3\\ 3&1&2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ in the symmetry group $S_3$ with composition from left to right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is: if the question is only asking for existence, will a counterexample suffice? It seems that it is still possible that there could exist $xyz = 1$ where $yz = zy$.

Comment: @JohnP. Of course there exist $x,y,z$ such that $xyz=1$ and $yz=zy$. As said in my answer, this happens when $x=y=z=1$. However, when the author asks "Does it follow that... $yxz=1$?", he is asking whether it is *necessarily* true that $yxz=1$. So, it takes only a counterexample to give a negative answer.

Comment: I must have misunderstood, but it's clear now -- thank you!